# how to retain the selected values in the form even after page refreshing

Tags: php

actually i'm new to php & i'm developing a project `SIMILAR TO ONLINE EXAMINTAION`.
so i'm display questionS `RANDOMLY FROM D`.B
what the thing is.
i'm displaying 5 questions `ALONG WITH THEIR  OPTIONS` in a single form.
and  i selected a radio button from a form & done page refreshing.the selected radio button can visible like unchecked after the page refreshing.so i want to display a radio button as checked which was selected by a user before page refreshing..is it possible.
or can u suggest a code to block the browser refresh button...

Comment: PHP works on the server side, you cannot do anything before a request to the server is made. You will need to write some JavaScript in order to accomplish the task

Answer (score 0):

Try the sisyphus http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/ - nice and easy to use JQuery plugin

Comment: i think it was not working in chrome/opera.any other beyond this

Comment: hi i can use that jquery plugin.it was working nice.but i want to clear the data which was stored in local storage when session ends.can u please help me how to clear the local storage

Answer (score 0):

You can store selected values in the cookies using javascript and on load event read cookies back and populate the values back.